# как открыть порт в Azure? Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, windows, azure

[image: проблема]

[image: порты]
[image: firewall]

На c# написал прогу, которая должна передавать с сервера на устройство текст, изображение и прогу(что-то типо магазина приложении), но при запуске возникает эта проблема как на 1 фото. Проблема заключается в портах. Я пытался открыть порты через Azure как на 2 фото, так же открывал через файрволл, но непомогает, что делать?

Вот код сервера

```
class Program
{
    const int port = 48657;
    public static string[] array = new string[10];
    static TcpListener listener;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start?");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        if (a == "yes")
        {
            try
            {
                listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
                listener.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    ClientObject clientObject = new ClientObject(client);
                    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clientObject.Process));
                    clientThread.Start();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.Stop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Program2.Main1("");
        }
    }
}
public class ClientObject
{
    public TcpClient client;
    public ClientObject(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        client = tcpClient;
    }
    string[] morearray(string[] array)
    {
        string[] arraynew = new string[array.Length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            arraynew[i] = array[i];
        }
        return arraynew;
    }
    public void Process()
    {
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[64]; // буфер для получаемых данных
            while (true)
            {
                // получаем сообщение
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                string message = builder.ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i < Program.array.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i + 1 == Program.array.Length)
                    {
                        Program.array = morearray(Program.array);
                    }
                    if (Program.array[i] == null)
                    {
                        if (message != "Connection")
                        {
                            Program.array[i] = message + "➽";
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                for (int i = 0; i < Program.array.Length; i++)
                {
                    message += Program.array[i];
                }
                data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
            if (client != null)
                client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы слушаете только на ip 127.0.0.1. Подставьте вместо него IPAddress.Any

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вам необходимо настроить Правила исходящего порта (с сервера наружу).
Если не удается это сделать на уровне ВМ, то это делается в обычном случае на уровне NSG (Сетевая группа безопасности), в которую сетевой данной ВМ входит.

Следуйте официальной документации по NSG:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/virtual-network/manage-network-security-group